# nested while loop printing bug

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested

the output I'm getting for looks like this:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 

 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 

 20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 

 30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39 

 40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49 

 50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59 

 60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69 

 70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79 

 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89 

 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 

100
```

I'm trying to get it to display by rows of 10.

```
row=1
column=1
while int(row) <= 10:
        while int(column) <= 10:
            print('{:3}'.format(int(row-1)*10+int(column)), end =' ')
            column = column +1
            if (column%10==0):
                print('\n')
        column = 1
        row = row + 1
```

This is the code I have for the above result. I have been able to get the desired result with a while loop, but I am unable to get the same result with this while loop.

Comment: Can you post your `for loop` that prints the results correctly.

Comment: Edit your question to add that code OP

Comment: move `column = column +1` below `print('\n')`

Comment: That created  an infinite loop. After playing with it some more I changed the 'if' line to: if (column%11==0): and I got the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 1
while number <= 100:
    print ('{:3}'.format(number), end=' ')
    if (number%10==0):
        print ("\n")
    number = number +1
```